# Mac MEX compiler error mathconvnet compilation

Tags: macos, matlab

I am trying to use mathconvnet on Matlab R2015b on my mac os 10.11. I am still in the installation stage. I have downloaded Xcode and when i try to use the command `vl_compilenn` it gives me the following error:

Error using mex
No supported compiler or SDK was found. For options, visit 
http://www.mathworks.com/support/compilers/R2015b/maci64.html.

Error in vl_compilenn>mex_compile (line 438)
mex(mopts{:}) ;

Error in vl_compilenn (line 400)
    mex_compile(opts, srcs{i}, toobj(bld_dir,srcs{i}), flags.mexcc) ;

This is my second day using a mac. I would really appreciate if someone could help me with a walkthrough on how to get it working.

Comment: well, go to the link, get some of those compiles, and then run `mex -setup`

Comment: I did go to the link. I have Xcode 7 installed. And running `mex -setup` gives me the following error: Error using mex
No supported compiler or SDK was found. For options, visit 
http://www.mathworks.com/support/compilers/R2015b/maci64.html.

Comment: And did you go to the link? Because it says `Xcode 5.1+ or 6.0`

Comment: I did. Maybe it is an issue with the newer version. I will try to install the older Xcode and try. Will report back

Comment: Yeah. It is! You need to use the versions MATLAB tells you. It doesnt say Xcode 5.1 or higher!

Comment: There's a fix to get Xcode 7.0 to work with your version of MATLAB.  Please see here: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/243868-mex-can-t-find-compiler-after-xcode-7-update-r2015b